# CSS : break spans into "table"

Tags: css

I have a small HTML structure :

```
 <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="item">dd</span>
        <span class="item">aaaaaaaa</span>
        <span class="item">cccc</span>
        <span class="item">Item 4</span>
        <span class="item">Item fsfsfdf</span>
        <span class="item">Id</span>
        <span class="item">Itsdsdsdsdsd sds dsd</span>
        <span class="item">365</span>
        <span class="item">7</span>
    </div>
```

I need to display these items in 3 columns and 3 rows. I cannot edit HTML, I cannot append any classes or change structure in anyway except order of spans.

I found a solution to break them into 3 lines :

```
.wrapper span:nth-child(3n+1):before {
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
}

.wrapper span:nth-child(1):before {
    content: "";
}
```

Now the "last" thing I need is to align them.

I tried :

1. Adding float:left and min-width on item class : works perfectlly in IE11 and Edge, doesn't work in other browsers
2. Playing with display:inline-table : Doesn't work : Some items has height modified for no reason.

Edit : complete test page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            font-size: 14px;
            padding-top: 3px;
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 0px;
            width: 500px;
            background-color: red;
        }

            .wrapper span {
                background-color: #fff;
                border-radius: 1px;
                margin-right: 15px;
                min-width: 125px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
                padding-left: 3px;
            }

                .wrapper span:nth-child(3n+1):before {
                    content: "\A";
                    white-space: pre;
                    color: green;
                }

                .wrapper span:nth-child(1):before {
                    content: "";
                }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="item">dd</span>
        <span class="item">aaaaaaaa</span>
        <span class="item">cccc</span>
        <span class="item">Item 4</span>
        <span class="item">Item fsfsfdf</span>
        <span class="item">Id</span>
        <span class="item">Itsdsdsdsdsd sds dsd</span>
        <span class="item">365</span>
        <span class="item">7</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: those are pretty awful requirements.

Comment: you can indeed use flex. margin can be used to simulate border-spacing https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VxqWmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using flexbox with `flex-wrap` should solve your issue:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 33.33333%; /* column width */
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="item">dd</span>
  <span class="item">aaaaaaaa</span>
  <span class="item">cccc</span>
  <span class="item">Item 4</span>
  <span class="item">Item fsfsfdf</span>
  <span class="item">Id</span>
  <span class="item">Itsdsdsdsdsd sds dsd</span>
  <span class="item">365</span>
  <span class="item">7</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Works fine, but I added width in px intead of % for my needs.

Comment: @VXp if you want to edit my answer at least explain why you do it. You've changed my solution to a worse one (no overflow handling) without explanation.

Comment: Worse one? Pure flexbox way, but now not anymore. Overflow handling can be simply dealt with word-break: break-all; ...

Comment: @VXp, that's assuming you want that behaviour and only have inline content. The task was to create 3 columns, that means they must stay fixed no matter what.

Comment: Don't see a requirement for that. Even if, then there's no need for flex: 0 0 auto; makes no difference.